# Fatal Error: Index out of range, when using search bar Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having a bit of an issue when trying to configure a search bar on a Table View.  my data in the Table View loads fine, and if I make a selection segues to the next screen with the correct information.  However on the Table View screen, as soon as I type a letter in the search bar, the app crashes with an Index out of range error.

Its a bit strange as previously I had this configured as a collection view, and the search bar worked fine.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var TR: Tracks!
var track = [Tracks]()
var filteredTrack = [Tracks]()
var inSearchMode = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done  

    parseTrackCSV()
}

func parseTrackCSV() {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tracks", ofType: "csv")!

    do {
        let csv = try CSV(contentsOfURL: path)
        let rows = csv.rows

        for row in  rows {
            let trackId = Int(row["id"]!)!
            let name = row["name"]!
            let postcode = row["postcode"]!
            let trackType = row["type"]!
            let locID = row["locID"]!
            let lon = Double(row["long"]!)!
            let lat = Double(row["lat"]!)!
            let tr = Tracks(name: name, trackId: trackId, postcode: postcode, trackType: trackType, locId: locID, lon: lon, lat: lat)
            track.append(tr)

            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return track.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrackCell", for: indexPath) as? TrackCell {
        let tr: Tracks!
        if inSearchMode {
            tr = filteredTrack[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(track: tr)
        } else {
            tr = track[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(track: tr)
        }
        cell.configureCell(track: tr)
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        let lower = searchBar.text!
        filteredTrack = track.filter({$0.name.range(of: lower) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()

     }
  }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var tr: Tracks!
    if inSearchMode {
        tr = filteredTrack[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        tr = track[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "TrackDetailVC", sender: tr)
}

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "TrackDetailVC" {
        if let detailsVC = segue.destination as? TrackDetailVC {
            if let tr = sender as? Tracks {
                detailsVC.track = tr
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The line that the break happens on is:

```
 tr = filteredTrack[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: is this (Monster's) solution worked for your?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning number of rows using track.count and trying to get value from filteredTrack, when your search is enabled. So obvious you must get the same error.
You need to set condition here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if inSearchMode {
     return filteredTrack.count
  } else {
     return track.count
  }

}
```

Comment: perfect thank you, just looked at my original code when I had the Collection view in place, and that condition was there, must of totally overlooked it, thank you.